# Length and size of strings in Elixir / Erlang needs explanation

Tags: erlang, elixir

Can someone explain why `s` is a string with 4096 chars

```
iex(9)> s = String.duplicate("x", 4096)
... lots of "x"
iex(10)> String.length(s)
4096
```

but its memory size are a few 6 words?

```
iex(11)> :erts_debug.size(s)
6 # WHAT?!
```

And why `s2` is a much shorter string than `s`

```
iex(13)> s2 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20"
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20"
iex(14)> String.length(s)
50
```

but its size has more 3 words than `s`?

```
iex(15)> :erts_debug.size(s2)
9 # WHAT!?
```

And why does the size of these strings does not match their lengths?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First clue why this is showing that values can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543248/why-the-memory-for-atom-is-zero-using-erts-debugsize-1#). Quoting `size/1` docs:

```
%% size(Term)
%%  Returns the size of Term in actual heap words. Shared subterms are
%%  counted once.  Example: If A = [a,b], B =[A,A] then size(B) returns 8,
%%  while flat_size(B) returns 12.
```

Second clue can be found in [Erlang documentation about bitstrings implementation](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#how-binaries-are-implemented).

---

So in the first case the string is too big to fit on heap alone, so it uses [refc binaries](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#refc-binaries) which are stored on **stack** and on heap there is only pointer to given binary.

In second case string is shorter than 64 bytes and it uses [heap binaries](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#heap-binaries) which is just array of bytes stored directly in on the heap, so that gives us `8 bytes per word (64-bit) * 9 = 72` and when we check documentation about exact memory overhead in VM we see that [Erlang uses `3..6` words per binary + `data`, where data can be shared](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#memory).

Comment: Also important to remember is that `size/1` counts `HEAP words`. And the links are very good. Thanks